# ordinal regression - polr "response must be a factor" error

Tags: r, regression, ordinal

I'm attempting an ordinal regression in R using polr.

I've imported my data:

```
data <-read.spss(...data file info..)
```

and have computed additional variables I need for the model, for example.

```
data$newvariable <-(data$x1 + data$x2 + data$x3 + data$x4)
```

I've then created the model:

```
model1 <- polr(outcome ~ pred1 + pred2+ pred3, data = data, Hess=TRUE, method = c("logistic"))
```

However, I get the error code:

```
Error in polr(outcome ~ pred1 + pred2 + pred3, data = data, Hess = TRUE,  : 
 response must be a factor
```

Any ideas on how to get around this? I'm still finding my feet with R, so apologies if this is a pretty standard question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution is pretty simple , just add `as.factor()` to the response.

```
model1 <- polr(as.factor(outcome) ~ pred1 + pred2+ pred3, data = data, Hess=TRUE, method = c("logistic"))
```